# how to get theme url in wordpress static page

Tags: wordpress, url, static, themes

I am new in wordpress. I added some static page in my wordprees website. In dynamic page we can get theme url by bloginfo('template_directory'); but it will not work in static page. so what is the alternative of this code for static page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a little Javascript:

```
location.pathname
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure! Use this function:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri

Let me know if you have any other issues.

Answer (score 0):

my problem is solved, thanks for reply. I use shortcode for getting theme link in page

//[themeurl]
function themeurl_func( $atts ){

```
return bloginfo('template_directory');
```

}
add_shortcode( 'themeurl', 'themeurl_func' );

and just write [themeurl] in page we can get themeurl in page